# Change text in view controller based on what cell was pressed

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I have a `UITableView` in the storyboard with lots of different cells and I want to have some text change in the `UIViewController` you get sent to when you press a cell. I don't know if this is possible in the storyboard or if I have to add code. Last time I made an app for iOS I just made a new `UIViewController` for every new button but that wouldn't work this time as I have about 30 different cells. If someone could point me in the right direction with a tutorial or something it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What have you tried? Have you done any research into this? You can google it and you get loads of results around this sort of thing.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the steps, it's not exact but it's similar

First Create a new Master Detail template project

[image]

Next step is select story board and iPhone

[image]

Now run the app. It almost what you want.

Comment: Ths isn´t what I asked. Sorry if I explained myself bad. I wanted to know how to make the text in the last View controller change based on what cell i pressed

Comment: @AKV his question depicts that he wan something like that :D